# Using a form search with fetch and display output in React

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have a simple search from that I'm create to display a crypto-currency price in React.

The api endpoint is `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{id}/`
Where `id` is the name of the coin. When I fetch the endpoint of `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/`, I get

> uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Constructor

```
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {value: ''};
     this.state = {coin: []};

     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

The handler

```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    let coin = this.state.value;
    this.findCoin(coin);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

the fetch

```
  findCoin(id) {
    fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/${id}`, {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    }).then((result)=> {
      debugger;
        result.json()
      .then(json => {
        debugger;
        this.setState({coin: json})
       });
    });
  }
```

Render

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           <label>
             Name:
             <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
           </label>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div> Price: {/* Price here */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Change `mode` of fetch method to "cors". That might be the issue.

Comment: if i dont set to `no-cors` then i get an error saying to use `no-cors`..

Comment: Then it seems your server endpoint doesn't support cors. Either you have to add cors support to the server or use a proxy if you can't change the server.

Comment: the api endpoint im trying to hit is https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `result.json()` function is failing with an exception. Because you don't have a `catch()` in the promise chain, it complains.

Try adding `catch()` to the end:

```
result.json()
  .then(json => {
    debugger;
    this.setState({
      coin: json
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    debugger
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: yes, but still doesnt explain why the fetch isnt returning anything. Also i still get an input error

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch` function needs a `Request` object to be passed to it instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

For example,

```
findCoin(id) {
  let endpoint = `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/${id}`;
  let request = new Request(endpoint);
  return fetch(request).then((body) => {
    return body.json().then((json) => {
      this.setState({ coin: json });
    });
  });
},
```